# Is it possible to sftp to multiple machines in single sftp command?

Tags: scripting, sftp

In my case, I want to sftp set of files to 3 machines using 1 sftp command in RHEL. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you give a little background?  What are the reasons for using 1 sftp command?  Convenience? Something you will be doing again and again?  If so, will the files vary, the machine names vary, or all the same each time?  Will you use this interactively or in a script? Anything that gives more context and background so that you'll get the best answer that works for you.

Comment: If it's essentially a manual task that needs to be applied to N machines, could `clusterssh` or `tmux` help you here? For example, `cssh host1 host2 host3 ... hostn` or even `cssh hostgroup1`

Answer (score 1):

Only technically: in a *for*-loop there is "one" sftp command.  And "scp" is more suited than the interactive `sftp`:

```
for target in $*;do scp foo $target: done
```

If you explain what features you need from `sftp`, someone can elaborate and show how the same for-loop could be adapted.